# Asus P8P67 PRO usb copy corruption and updating USB Drivers and chipset drivers

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, motherboard, chipset

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit (updated all important updates yesterday) and have several external usb hard drives (self powered 3.5 inch).  I recently noticed while copying files to the external drive and then using a utility to compare the original files (internal drive) to the files just copied to the external drive that the files often don't match on a byte for byte comparison.  I would find that one byte has changed on the files randomly.

This is really disturbing as it happens with several external hard drives, for example a western digital and seagate and I can't rely on a proper copy to the drives.  It was suggested that I upgrade my motherboard chipset drivers and while downloading the drivers I also noticed that they have a few usb driver updates as well.

Also please note that this corruption still happens after updating windows.

My first question is what is causing this issue and how can I fix it.

The second question is, how do i know which usb driver (and chipset driver) to install?

I downloaded the drivers from:

```
http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=39&m=P8P67%20PRO&os=29&hashedid=HMMvTCuBcZLfu2YL
```

In device manager -> Universal Serial Bus controller i have a lot of items listed, among them, i have 2 `"ASMedia XHCI Controller"` items.
Their driver details say that the driver date is 2010/12/08 and version is 1.4.5.0

I have never upgraded chipset drivers or usb drivers before (just installed the ones that came on my motherboard dvd when i first got my computer) so i'm not sure of the procedure etc. Can I recover in case of error with a system restore point?

Doing some research it is really confusing as to which driver i should install for both usb and chipset.  For example, should i install:

```
NEC USB 3.0 Driver V2.0.4.0 for Windows 32/64bit XP & Windows 32/64bit Vista & 32/64bit Windows 7
```

or

```
Renesas(NEC) USB3.0 Controller Driver V2.0.32.0 for Windows XP/Vista/7 32bit & 64bit.(WHQL)
```

Looking online it's unclear, some say NEC is Renesas, some say there should still be an ASMedia driver available and the version they list as the latest have a higher version that the ones from the Asus site.